# Formula field: Concatenate Picklist and text field

Tags: formula, formula-field

I am trying to create a formula that concatenates the following fields:

```
mytext__c (text field) -- example: tt
mynumber__c (number field) -- example: 10
mypicklist__c (picklist field) -- example: no
```

I want to create a field "`code__c`" which is a formula and looks like this:

```
tt-10-no
```

This is what I have right now:

```
mytext__c + mynumber__c + TEXT(mypicklist__c)
```

For some reason I am getting an error for the picklist though.
Tia.

Comment: please update error  and formula field datatype/returntype...

Answer (score 5):

The symbol used for string concatenation is "&" rather than "+". You also need to use the TEXT() function on the number field to convert it into a string.

```
mytext__c & "-" & TEXT(mynumber__c) & "-" & TEXT(mypicklist__c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below I show How can You create Formula For Formula Field

textField1__c  & '-' & Text(NumberField__c) &  '-' & Text(PicklistField__c)